# gcc thinks MMX registers are "bad register name"s

Tags: cpu-architecture

I'm trying to optimize the calculation of a dot product by using the registers and instructions included in the MMX and SSE extentions.

When I insert the line seen below, though, gcc is giving me an error about bad register names for %xxmX registers

```
 .L3:
    movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
    leal    0(,%eax,4), %edx
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movups  (%eax), %xxm0       <--------------------
    flds    (%eax)
    movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
    leal    0(,%eax,4), %edx
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    flds    (%eax)
    fmulp   %st, %st(1)
    flds    -4(%ebp)
    faddp   %st, %st(1)
    fstps   -4(%ebp)
    addl    $1, -8(%ebp)
```

when compiled with

```
 gcc -m32 -march=corei7 dot_product.s
```

I get

```
 dot_product.s: Assembler messages:
 dot_product.s:24: Error: bad register name `%xxm0'
```

I have the corei7 architecture as show below

```
 dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

yields

```
 i386
 corei7
```

any idea why gcc is throwing an error?

Comment: May be because x**m**m and not x**x**m ??

Comment: oh... my... goodness

Comment: I must have dyslexia or something, thank you... I feel very stupid now